# Finding Cramer Rao Lower bound for a bivariate parameter

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, gamma-distribution, fisher-information

I am having a hard time figuring out the Cramer Rao lower bound for a random sample of size $n$ from a population with $\Gamma(p, \theta)$ with $p, \theta$ unknown. The problem doesn't say what formulation to use for the gamma function, but I have used

$$
f(x|p, \theta) = \frac{\theta^p}{\Gamma(p)} x^{p-1} e^{-\theta x} I_{[0,\infty)}(x).
$$

So I know that I have to find the Fisher Information matrix and compute the inverse, however the entries I get are not "nice". The derivatives of the logarithm of the pdf is (considering only $x_1$)

$$
\frac{ \partial }{ \partial p} \ln f(x_1|p,\theta) = \ln \theta - \frac{\partial}{\partial p} (\ln \Gamma (p)) + \ln x_1, \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln f(x_1|p,\theta) = \frac{p}{\theta}-x_1.
$$

Now, the entries in the Fisher Information matrix would be, with $\beta = [p, \theta]^\mathrm{T}$,

$$
I_{ij} = n \mathrm{E} \left[ \left( \frac{ \partial}{\partial \beta_i} \ln f(X| p, \theta) \right) \left( \frac{ \partial}{\partial \beta_j} \ln f(X| p, \theta) \right)  \right].
$$

However, with the derivatives obtained above the entries become horrible... Apart from $I_{22} = np/\theta^2 $, that is. Am I on the right track here?